# instanceof Array and Array.isArray don't narrow generic type to Array

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm making a function merging two arrays or objects of same type for React like:

```
import {Dispatch, SetStateAction, useEffect} from "react";

function useConcat<S extends Object, T = S extends Array<infer E> ? E[] : S>(dispatch: Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>, state: T) {
    useEffect(() => {
        if (state) {
            if (state instanceof Array) { // or Array.isArray(state)
                // state is type T & any[] and that makes the error
                dispatch(prev => [...prev, ...state]);
            }
            else {
                dispatch(prev => ({...prev, ...state}));
            }

            return () => {
                // ...
            };
        }

        return;
    }, [state]);
}
```

which generates error:

```
Type '(prev: T) => any[]' is not assignable to type '(prevState: T) => T'.
    Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'T'.
      'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'any[]'.ts(2345)
```

How can I make it work?

I'm using version 4.3.5.

Comment: try `S[]` instead

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar I tried `function useConcat<S extends Object, T = S extends Array<infer E> ? E[] : S>(dispatch: Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>, state: T)`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: `S` is unused generic parameter. It is not binded to value

Answer (score 0):

It is the `dispatch` function that was not convinced to be `Dispatch<SetStateAction<E[]>>`, so you can try type assertion.

```
function useConcat<T extends object>(
  dispatch: Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>,
  state: T,
) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (state) {
      if (state instanceof Array) {
        // or Array.isArray(state)
        (dispatch as Dispatch<SetStateAction<unknown[]>>)(prev => [
          ...prev,
          ...state,
        ]);
      } else {
        dispatch(prev => ({ ...prev, ...state }));
      }

      return () => {
        // ...
      };
    }

    return;
  }, [state]);
}
```